# Accessing UVC camera controls from PyGST

Tags: python, gstreamer, webcam, pygst

I'm using PyGST to display the feed from a UVC webcam inside a PyQt application. I can access some camera controls, such as brightness and contrast, directly using the corresponding properties of the `v4l2src` elements. However, I'd like to access additional controls, namely focus, available through `v4l2-ctl`. My understanding is that such controls should be accessible through the `extra-controls` property (`extra_controls` in Python) of the `v4l2src` element. However, the property is empty at runtime after the pipeline is started. What am I missing?

EDIT: minimal sample

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import uic
import subprocess
import re

#GStreamer libraries
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GstVideo
Gst.init(None)

class WebcamTest(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(640,480)
        self.gst_video = VideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gst_video)
        self.gst_video.prepare()

class VideoWidget(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VideoWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(qtc.Qt.WA_NativeWindow)
        self.windowId = self.winId()
        qtw.qApp.sync()
        self.pipeline = None

    def prepare(self):
        pipeline = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 name=source ! image/jpeg, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1, format=MJPG ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink"

        self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)
        self.source = self.pipeline.get_child_by_name('source')

        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        bus.connect('sync-message::element', self.on_sync_message)
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        print(f'source properties: {self.source.list_properties()}')
        print(f'brightness={self.source.props.brightness}')
        print(f'extra-controls={self.source.props.extra_controls}')

    def on_sync_message(self, bus, msg):
        message_name = msg.get_structure().get_name()
        # qtc.qDebug(message_name)
        if message_name == 'prepare-window-handle':
            win_id = self.windowId
            assert win_id
            imagesink = msg.src
            imagesink.set_window_handle(win_id)

    def dispose(self):
        if (self.pipeline):
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.pipeline = None
    
    def isPlaying(self):
        return self.pipeline.current_state == Gst.State.PLAYING

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_ui = WebcamTest()
    main_ui.move(200,100)
    main_ui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

List of available controls from the camera:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -l
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-64 max=64 step=1 default=0 value=0
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=64 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=128 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-40 max=40 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
    white_balance_red_component 0x0098090e (int)    : min=1 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=100 flags=inactive
   white_balance_blue_component 0x0098090f (int)    : min=1 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=100 flags=inactive
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=72 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=100
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=0 value=0
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1
                       hue_auto 0x00980919 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4600 value=4600 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=6 step=1 default=3 value=3
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=2 step=1 default=1 value=1
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=5000 step=1 default=157 value=157 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1
                 focus_absolute 0x009a090a (int)    : min=1 max=1023 step=1 default=1 value=688
                     focus_auto 0x009a090c (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                zoom_continuous 0x009a090f (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0 flags=write-only
                        privacy 0x009a0910 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                  iris_absolute 0x009a0911 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0
                  iris_relative 0x009a0912 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0 flags=write-only
                      pan_speed 0x009a0920 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0
                     tilt_speed 0x009a0921 (int)    : min=0 max=0 step=0 default=0 value=0
```

EDIT: Found a way to change a parameter, for instance this snippet will activate the auto focus:

```
        extra_controls = Gst.Structure.new_from_string('i,focus_auto=1')
        self.source.set_property('extra_controls', extra_controls)
```

However, I still don't understand how to query current values of other controls (similarly to what I can get with `v4l2-ctl -l`).

Comment: Can you share you code? The `extra-controls` need to be a GstStructure type to take effect.

Comment: @votelessbubble done. After the pipeline started, `self.source.props.extra_controls` is `None`. I was expecting to find the extra controls automatically enumerated.